# I use APK-MITM for Inspecting a mobile app's But i have error how fix?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

this is error form APK-MITM

```
I: Using Apktool 2.6.1
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes10 folder into classes10.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes11 folder into classes11.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes12 folder into classes12.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes13 folder into classes13.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes14 folder into classes14.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes15 folder into classes15.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes16 folder into classes16.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes17 folder into classes17.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes2 folder into classes2.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes3 folder into classes3.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes4 folder into classes4.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes5 folder into classes5.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes6 folder into classes6.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes7 folder into classes7.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes8 folder into classes8.dex...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali_classes9 folder into classes9.dex...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: C:\Users\NOSF3R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-mitm-7c864f56c00fb32ce67023d7ee2b897d\decode\AndroidManifest.xml:1012: error: unexpected element <uses-native-library> found in <manifest><application>.
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\NOSF3R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_96446175879549352302894172467481812474.tmp, link, -o, C:\Users\NOSF3R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL3174150779616533506.tmp, --package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 26, --target-sdk-version, 33, --version-code, 130920301, --version-name, 13.9.2, --no-auto-version, --no-version-vectors, --no-version-transitions, --no-resource-deduping, -e, C:\Users\NOSF3R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL7214016274299369628.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\NOSF3R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-mitm-7c864f56c00fb32ce67023d7ee2b897d\framework\1.apk, --manifest, C:\Users\NOSF3R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-mitm-7c864f56c00fb32ce67023d7ee2b897d\decode\AndroidManifest.xml, C:\Users\NOSF3R~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-mitm-7c864f56c00fb32ce67023d7ee2b897d\decode\build\resources.zip]
```

i can generate apk app

Comment: apktool 1.6.1 is outdated, latest version is 1.7.0. `<uses-native-library>` is an Manifest entry which was added in Android 12. Most likely the error you encounter is the same as discussed in [issue 2778](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/2778) which had been fixed in 1.7.0.